# DeploymentLimitExceededException AWS CodeDeploy

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy

Im getting DeploymentLimitExceededException from AWS CodeDeploy.

Im using Codeship to deploy.

Where i can see my "acccount deployment limit"?

Any help?

Comment: Are you using EB, right?

Comment: Are you using EB, right? if yes, i had this problem,  you can remove deploy's versions from the your enviroment in EB Console, click in **Upload and Deploy**  below of the current version, and in the modal that will  be opened click in the **link To deploy a previous version, go to the _Application Versions page_.** , so than you can select the oldest versions and remove then.

Comment: Sorry, i never used the Code Deploy yet, but maybe exists something  like what i commented.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default limit is 10. See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/limits.html#limits-deployments

There is no API that lets you discover what your limits are.